# Stop Typescript compiling files from which I only import types

Tags: typescript

I came across an unexpected problem compiling some test code using Typescript.

My tests import **types** from my app code, but that's it. Just the types, no actual logic. When I go to compile the tests with `tsc` though, I find in the output directory that the app code files I imported the types from, and all the files they import, are there, and have been compiled.

It's annoying because it messes up the structure of the output directory. The entry point for the tests is at `./tests/src/index.js` and I want the compiled output to be at `./output/index.js` - instead because of the imported app code messing up the structure it gets output to another directory much deeper down - `./output/tests/src/index.js`.

Here's a demonstration of the problem with a simplified example

Source files, all in same directory

```
-- a.ts --
import { SomeType } from './b' // I ONLY import a type from b.ts, no actual code
import { someFunction } from './c'

const someValue: SomeType = { hello: 'world' }
someFunction(someValue.hello)

-- b.ts --
export type SomeType = { hello: string }

export const someUnusedFunction = () => {
  console.log('this is never used')
}

-- c.ts --
export const someFunction = (x: string) => {
  console.log(x)
}

-- d.ts --
export const neverImported = () => {
  console.log('this file is never imported')
}
```

I run this command, compiling with `a.ts` as the entry point

```
tsc -module commonjs --moduleResolution node --outDir ./output ./a.ts
```

What I would expect would be for `a.js` and `c.js` to get compiled to `./output`, as they're the only files with any javascript code in them which is executed by `a.js`. I'd expect `b.js` not to appear because I only imported a type from it, no code, and `d.js` not to appear because it's not imported by anything.

Instead, I find that `a.js` `b.js` and `c.js` appear. It seems Typescript is compiling `b.js` unnecessarily, just because I imported a type from it. Note that it *doesn't* compile and output `d.js`, as expected.

I don't understand why it would do that, it seems really obvious that no code in `b.js` is ever imported by anything in the dependency tree, just as is the case with `d.js`. I can't see a usecase where you'd want that behaviour, though perhaps there is one I'm not thinking of.

**Is there a way to turn this off in Typescript, and only have it compile files from which I import actual code?**

---

This is the compiled output of the above, by the way. You can see that there's no mistake here -- `b.js` isn't actually imported or referenced anywhere by accident -- you can clearly see that `a.js` only `require`s `c.js`.

```js
-- ./output/a.js --
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var c_1 = require("./c");
var someValue = {
    hello: 'world'
};
c_1.someFunction(someValue.hello);

-- ./output/b.js --
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
exports.someUnusedFunction = function () {
    console.log('this is never used');
};

-- ./output/c.js --
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
exports.someFunction = function (x) {
    console.log(x);
};
```

Comment: I think I'm hitting this same problem. I'm trying to build exactly one file with Typescript, and ignore building any imported files.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option in typescript for this. There has been in [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22864) in the typescript repo for this but it was discarded since there are build tools that can change the emit policy as needed.

Comment: Thanks. It's definitely related but the linked issue is about something subtly different - tsc compiling .ts files containing no js code at all to empty .js files. It's kind of a special case of the issue I'm seeing, though, I guess.